# What is the simplest lightest way to see if there is a true statement in a hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I have this hash :

```
{:thursday=>false, :friday=>false, :monday=>false, :saturday=>false, :sunday=>false, :tuesday=>false, :wednesday=>false}
```

What is the simplest, lightest way to identify if **any** of them are **true**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you're looking for "pure" `true`, use

```
hash.has_value?( true )
```

else use something like this

```
hash.detect{|key,value| value }  
# or
hash.detect{|key,value| !!value } 
# or even
if_nil = Proc.new{ "this will be called if no matching value is found" }
hash.detect( if_nil ) {|key,value| !!value }
```